# Look for a function that gives a symmetrical curve with flexible curvature

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

I am searching for a function that would relate two variables approximately like the graphs below, but with a smooth curve.

[image]

The joint of the dark line above is where users can click with a mouse, thus specifying the function to be applied.

Both my variables, `Tamanho` (size) and `Nº spp` (species number) are within the range [0,1].

The curve should become an almost square near the corners, i.e. (`Nº spp` ~ 0 and `Tamanho` ~ 1) or (`Nº spp` ~ 1 and `Tamanho` ~ 0).

[image]

I have tried exponential functions, but they are not symmetrical.

[image]

I have also tried quadratic curves, but they goes outside the range [0,1] for `Tamanho`, depending on where you click.

Question:

Does such function I'm looking for even exist? If not, what options do I have?

I'm going to include them all in my program (broken line, exponential...), so the bigger the number of options, the better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a perfect curve that meets all the requirements:

$$(1+a^2)(y-x)^2=a^2+(x+y)^2$$

where $a$ is a parameter that adjusts how sharp the turn is. The sample plot below is for $a=0.05$.

As seen in the graph, the function exists. It has the desired symmetry and stays within the unit range. In the limit $a\rightarrow 0$, a 90-degree corner turn (nearly a square) can be produced.

[image]

$$a=0.05$$

Comment: That's awesome! But how do I isolate the y, so as to draw the graph on my program? I'm getting stuck in there. Should I ask a new question, maybe?

Comment: Also I got curious: how did you find this equation? You just thought of it? Trial and error? Or is it similar to some you already knew?

Comment: You can express y in terms of x and obtain the function y(x) explicitly. Just expand the curve equation  and solve the resulting quadratic equation. Note that there are two solutions, corresponding to the two curves in the plot.

Comment: I was able to isolate `a`, so I can calculate it when the user clicks on the graph (`x` and `y` are known). Knowing `a` (and `x` being on the interval `[0,1]`), I need to calculate `y` to draw the graph. I got to $y(-4x+a^2y-2xa^2)=a^2(1-x^2)$ and now I just can't isolate the `y`.

Comment: OK, never mind. I got it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

It can’t exist as a function $y=f(x)$ if you impose the graph to be a square *if you click of the bottom right corner*. Indeed for the graph you draw, there is an infinite number of images of $x =1$.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't have to be a vertical line. It could end at [1,0], and I draw the vertical line outside the function. Or it could come very close to [1,0], and I'd round it at the program interface.

Comment: Updated the question to make it clearer. Thank you.